# correct approach to compare dates (in string format) using perl script

Tags: perl, datetime, compare

i am new to perl scripting. can you please help to compare two date.
i have

```
my $dt1 = "20171026";
my $dt2 = "20180101";
```

i am using the below snippet to compare dates, however i am not sure if this is the right way

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $dt1 = "20171026";
my $dt2 = "20180101";
if ($dt1 > $dt2){
    print "Hi";
}
else {
print "hello";
}
```

can anyone please suggest me if i can format a string say $dt1 to date time format and compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison is fine.

Since your *dates* are really just numbers, and they are in YMD format, a numerical comparison work. The components of the date are sorted by their importance, which is key here.

- Year first: `2017` is always before `2018`
- Month second: October (`10`) is later than January (`01`), but the leading zero is important
- Day: same thing, `05` would be before `29`

So to compare

- `20170101` is before `20170102`
- `20180101` is after `20171231`

because it's all just numbers.

For this format there is absolutely no need or benefit from using a date module and parsing the strings. It will not make it easier to read, nor faster. It will just increase the complexity of your code.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the YYYYMMDD (or %Y%m%d) format, you can compare the dates as numbers or strings. It means both

```
$dt1 > $dt2
```

and

```
$dt1 gt $dt2
```

work correctly. I prefer to use string comparison (`gt ge lt le eq ne`) as we don't use the dates as numbers (we don't add numbers to them etc.) but as strings (you can e.g. extract the year by `substr $dt, 0, 4`). Also, string comparison still works if you use a separator, e.g. 2018/09/25.

Comment: The string comparison also gives you the added benefit of working on `2018-09-26`.

Comment: String comparison also still works on the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, as well as ISO-8601 (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ) provided they are all in the same time zone and you use 24 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

One can compare strings with dates in such format, as explained, but that's all you can do.

There are of course libraries for date-time work, as I think the question asks.

The most comprehensive one is [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime), which is extremely rounded in functionality

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => '%y%m%d' );
my $dt1 = $format->parse_datetime($dt1_str);
my $dt2 = $format->parse_datetime($dt2_str);

if ($dt1 < $dt2) { say $dt1->ymd, " is earlier than ", $dt2->ymd }
```

Now you can do all kinds of things with those dates, see documentation.

If you don't need all that much to do and would prefer a far lighter module, there is  [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html)

```
use Time::Piece;

my $dt1 = Time::Piece->strptime($dt1_str, "%Y%m%d");
my $dt2 = Time::Piece->strptime($dt2_str, "%Y%m%d");

if ($dt1 < $dt2) { say $dt1->ymd, " is earlier than ", $dt2->ymd }
```

which is also simpler to use, for simple things. It comes with a few other conveniences, but if your needs grow more complex be careful as some of the module's interfaces can be tricky.

Comment: DateTime is a little bit more wordy, but that's a side-effect of it being hard to misuse. Time::Piece, otoh, is very easy to use incorrectly.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you very much for the edit; I wanted a most basic example and completely forgot about DateTime's formatting extensions.